# Show that an abelian group $G$ of order $100$ cannot act faithfully on a set with $13$ elements.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, sylow-theory

> Show that an abelian group $G$ of order $100$ cannot act faithfully on a set with $13$ elements.

I am given the hint: Consider the $5$-Sylow subgroup $H$ of $G$ and determine its centralizer in $S_{13}$.

$|H|=25$ so $|\phi(H)|=25$. Now $\phi(H)$ is abelian and so its centralizer contains at least $25$ elements. I am not sure what to do next. I am not really sure how the centralizer is helpful here.

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051470/the-centralizer-of-a-cycle-is-the-group-generated-by-the-elements-of-s-n-that     you can show that the centralizer contains 25 * 6 elements exactly.